# get method can't retrieve all the data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering how would I retrieve the values inside a particular key id? I have used push() when inserting some information into firebase and when I tried to retrieve it by doing the following, I get the value of "Id" instead of either "piano0011" or "musician8888". I am trying to retrieve those ids, so that I can use it to make some comparison if statements...

```
 for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Information info = childSnapshot.getValue(Information.class);
                        String Id = String.valueOf(childSnapshot.child("Id").getKey());
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for us to know what data is in your `childSnapshot` variable, so it'd be good to next time see how you get that snapshot.

But this line looks suspicious for two reasons:

```
String Id = String.valueOf(childSnapshot.child("Id").getKey())
```

1. No property in your screenshot called `Id`. There's only `id` with a lowercase `i`.
2. Your `childSnapshot.child("Id").getKey()` will return `Id`, because that is the key. If you want the value of the `Id` property, it'd be: `childSnapshot.child("Id").getValue()` (and if its a string value: `childSnapshot.child("Id").getValue(String.class)`).

Comment: thanks but how do you return the push() variable? such as that long variable displayed on the screen?

Comment: I think my child(Id).getValue() returns null

Comment: To get the key of the child node you're iterating over, you'd use `childSnapshot.getKey()`.

Comment: Can someone also tell me whether we should always use the get method to retrieve information from the database or can we just pull it directly from it? I have set my set methods before inserting into the database but for some reason, at times, I am getting null, only when using the get method...